# baseurl not working in Jekyll

Tags: javascript, css, jekyll

I was trying to create a github page in "myaccount.github.io/Templates". While using Jekyll I set the `baseurl : /templates` but when visiting the above link, the JS and css files are not loading. The head.html goes like this (which gets included in the home page):

```
<head>
  <link href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" rel="profile">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

  <!-- Enable responsiveness on mobile devices-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">

  <title>
    {% if page.title == "Home" %}
      {{ site.title }} &middot; {{ site.tagline }}
    {% else %}
      {{ page.title }} &middot; {{ site.title }}
    {% endif %}
  </title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}public/css/poole.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}public/css/syntax.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}public/css/hyde.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700|Abril+Fatface">

  <!-- Icons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="{{ site.baseurl }}public/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
                                 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ site.baseurl }}public/favicon.ico">

  <!-- RSS -->
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="/atom.xml">
</head>
```

index.html:

```
---
layout: default
title: Home
---

<div class="posts">
  {% for post in paginator.posts %}
  <div class="post">
    <h1 class="post-title">
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">
        {{ post.title }}
      </a>
    </h1>

    <span class="post-date">{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span>

    {{ post.content }}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="pagination">
  {% if paginator.next_page %}
    <a class="pagination-item older" href="{{ site.baseurl }}page{{paginator.next_page}}">Older</a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="pagination-item older">Older</span>
  {% endif %}
  {% if paginator.previous_page %}
    {% if paginator.page == 2 %}
      <a class="pagination-item newer" href="{{ site.baseurl }}">Newer</a>
    {% else %}
      <a class="pagination-item newer" href="{{ site.baseurl }}page{{paginator.previous_page}}">Newer</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% else %}
    <span class="pagination-item newer">Newer</span>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Layouts : (default.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en-us">

  {% include head.html %}

  <body>

    {% include sidebar.html %}

    <div class="content container">
      {{ content }}
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why the css files are not loading !

Comment: Did you take a look at the generated source and directories, i.e. the files in _site? That might tell you what has happened.

Comment: Have you any solution to provide?

Answer (score 0):

If your url is **myaccount.github.io/Templates**, then your base url is :

```
baseurl: "/Templates" # Uppercase T
```